# JSON-API design

Tags: rest, crud, restful-architecture, json-api

Lets say I have different kind of objects `House` and `Car`. Now I want to add comments.

Whats better practise?
Having endpoints:

`/api/house/:houseId/comments`

`/api/car/:carId/comments`

Or a general api for comments like:

`/api/comments/:generalId`

Comment: Without much formal education in API design, I would say that the former is better because it is more structured - I see it as the difference between having productA.comments/productB.comments vs a big array comments[]

Comment: my concern here was, that in the API code I get dependencies to the comments.model from every object. so the readability of the the API is worth more than the structure on the API-code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for me product type is implementation detail. To be REST-style I would create API with

**/api/product/[productID]**

This endpoint would suport GET (get given product),POST (update given product), DELETE

**/api/product/**

This endpoint would support GET (get all products), PUT (create new product)

**/api/product/[productID]/comments/[commentID]**

This endpoint would support GET(get given comment for given product) and POST (update given comment), DELETE(delete given comments).
In this case, commentID may be unique only per resource, not globally.

**/api/product/[productID]/comments**

This endpoint will support GET (get all comments for product) and PUT(create new comment), DELETE (delete all comments for product)

**api/comments/[commentId]**

This resource (with operations GET, POST, DELETE) is also fine. But it needs globaly unique commentId. Feel free to expose such endpoint if you need to manage separate comments without knowing productId. This does not violate REST.

In this API design we  have separate resources for each product and comment.
We also have resource for all products, and resource for all comments for given product. Each of this resource may support GET,POST,PUT,DELETE. You may ommit some operations (for example do not expose `POST` on `/api/product/[productID]/comments/[commentID]` when you do not want to support editing comments.

Edit: as suggested in comments by @lospejos you may use plural forms (products, comments). Either way, your API will be REST-style, with every post/comment being separate resource.

Comment: I agree except I would use plurals for entities: `/products`, `/comments` etc in every endpoint

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough at the question. The products can't be only one endpoint. Its more like /api/house and /api/car. I edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: ok, so make /api/house/[id] and /api/car/id. Or encode product type in id, like /api/house.[house-id] /api/car.[car-id]/. Either way to be RESfull you need unique rerource id (URL) for each separate resource.

Comment: its about the comments. so you recommend to have /api/house/:id/comments and /api/car/:id/comments over /api/comments/:objectId?

Comment: yes, I reccomend 
 /api/house/:id/comments

That way, it is more clear that you have separate resources /api/house and  /api/house/:id. The longer URL, the more specific given resource becomes.

In any case /api/comments/:commentId is also valid resource! It makes sense to have separate, unique resource for each comment and a way to reffer to comment without resource id. But I would definetly see commentId, not resourceId there.

Comment: I do not like /api/comments/:objectId - when ObjectId is productId (not commentId). For me, that desing would suprise end-users. Also, you would loose a way to manage (get, update, delete) separate comments. If you want to mange all comments for given product, I strongly reccomend /api/products/[productId]/comments